# Wireless connection doesnt work on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 10.04, broadcom

I have dual booted my dell laptop with ubuntu 10.04. In ubuntu wireless networks are not getting detected while wired connection works. In windows wifi networks are detected and works without a problem. I have tried installing the broadcom drivers still it doesnt work. Can some one help me please.

the output for the command **sudo lshw -C network** is

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 04
   serial: d4:be:d9:53:1b:08
   size: 1GB/s
   capacity: 1GB/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.3.17-NAPI duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=172.23.212.51 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1GB/s
   resources: irq:20 memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff memory:f7e39000-f7e39fff ioport:f080(size=32)
```

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller

```
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 34
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
```

Comment: Please update to Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 support period is over. Kindly update your OS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 10.04 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.